# AEM 6.1, HTL:: Unable to apply style to a piece of text

Tags: aem, htl

Here is a piece of code in the HTL file of a component:

```
<p id="info" data-sly-use.info="info-text.js">
    ${info.text}
</p>
```

and this is the info-text.js

```
use(function () {

    // TODO: change currentStyle to wcm.currentStyle

    var CONST = {
        PROP_INFO_TEXT: "infoText",
        PROP_DEFAULT_TEXT: "Enter information text here"
    }

    var info = {};

    // The actual title content
    info.text = granite.resource.properties[CONST.PROP_INFO_TEXT]
        || CONST.PROP_DEFAULT_TEXT


    return info;
});
```

PROP_DEFAULT_TEXT is the default text which shows up on the page when the infoText property is not authored yet. I am looking to somehow provide style to this default text "Enter information text here". I tried using

```
PROP_DEFAULT_TEXT: "<p style='default-text'>Enter information text here</p>"
```

but on the page it appears like simple text as below:

[image]

I am not sure if I have use HTL Context to make it work and I try a few things but it won't work. So, I don't know what exactly should I do to make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You’re looking for @context=‘html’

Comment: @AhmedMusallam thank you for response. Yes, I tried it like this ${info.text @ context='html'} meanwhile setting the default string as PROP_DEFAULT_TEXT: "<p style='default-text'>Enter information text here</p>" but the text won't even show up. I am definitely doing something wrong here.

Comment: I have just tried it on my AEM 6.3 instance. and it works as expected. you can use this REPL: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl for quick testing.

Comment: It's working. My bad. Instead of p class I was using p style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `style="default-text"` is not correct CSS, please use correct CSS rules with `style` attribute.

Second, when trying to render HTML via HTL expression, you must set the display context to `html`:

`${info.text @context='html'}`

> Note: use [github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl](http://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl) for quick HTL testing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured and then updated that in my last comment. Thanks for your response.